# postgresql unique constraint for any integer from two columns (or from array)

Tags: postgresql

How to guarantee a uniqueness of **any** integer from the two columns / array?

Example: I create a table and insert one row in it:

```
CREATE TABLE mytest(a integer NOT NULL, b integer NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO mytest values (1,2);
```

What `UNIQUE INDEX` should I create to not allow add any of the following values

```
INSERT INTO mytest values (1,3); # because 1 is already there
INSERT INTO mytest values (3,1); # because 1 is already there
INSERT INTO mytest values (2,3); # because 2 is already there
INSERT INTO mytest values (3,2); # because 2 is already there
```

I can have array of two elements instead of two columns if it helps somehow.

Surely, I can invent some workaround, the following come into my mind:

- create separate table for all numbers, have `unique index` there, and add values to two tables with transaction. If the number is not unique, it won't be added to the second table, and transaction fails
- add two rows instead of one, and have additional field for `id-of-the-pair`.

But I want to have one table and I need one row with two elements in it. Is that possible?

Comment: A unique index / constraint isn't going to be enough here, but you might be able to do something with [an exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE). I've seen them described as a kind of "super generalised unique constraint", but never actually used one, and the manual seems rather light on examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use exclusion constraint on table along with intarray to quickly perform search of overlapping arrays:

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
CREATE TABLE test (
    a int[],
    EXCLUDE USING gist (a gist__int_ops WITH &&)
);

INSERT INTO test values('{1,2}');

INSERT INTO test values('{2,3}');
>> ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "test_a_excl"
>> DETAIL:  Key (a)=({2,3}) conflicts with existing key (a)=({1,2}).
```

Comment: You don't need to store that as an array in the table. `EXCLUDE USING gist ((array[a,b]) WITH &&)` will work as well