# postgresql. uniqueness for two columns

Tags: postgresql

I need to create unique index for table with two fields (email, alternative_email). It means one email address can be mentioned only one time in two columns. Also alternative email can be empty.

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   email VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
   alternative_email VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL default ''
);
```

Data:

```
insert into customers (email, alternative_email) 
values ('test@example.com', ''); - ok

insert into customers (email, alternative_email) 
values ('test1@example.com', 'test@example.com');
```

Second row should not be inserted because alternative_email = `'test@example.com'` already mentioned as `email` in first row.

How to create index to do this ?

Comment: What about the alternative_email? Should that also be unique across all rows?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `NOT NULL default ''` seems like an odd choice if you don't require an alternative email

Comment: Something like this maybe? `create unique index on customers ( (coalesce(nullif(alternative_email, ''), email)));`

Comment: seems it works. Thanks

Comment: No, it doesn't. I managed insert row. 
 id |       email       | alternative_email 
----+-------------------+-------------------
  1 | test2@example.com | test5@example.com
  2 | test5@example.com | test2@example.com

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create an index across two columns like that. What you need to do is change your design such that emails are all in one column in a different table.

So you could have a table called `emails` like:

```
CREATE TABLE emails (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   email VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);
```

Then have a many-to-many table that maps the customers to emails:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_emails (
   customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES customers(id),
   email_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES emails(id),
   alternative boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
   PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, email_id)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customer_email_idx ON customer_emails(customer_id, alternative);
```

This enforces that 2 different customers cannot reuse the same email address, that a customer can have at most one primary and one alternative email address, and the same email address cannot be used for both primary and alternative email addresses of the same customer.

Comment: If those were integers you can actually create such a constraint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40935314/ but unfortunately that doesn't work with varchar arrays

Comment: Yes, on integer arrays to be precise.

Comment: Good to know about it. So if the OP decided to put email addresses in a separate table, the foreign keys would then be integer IDs which then could be put in an integer array with your technique too.